# Why does my fill between in tikz produce weird results?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, fillbetween

I am trying to fill the area between some linear functions. But the resulting fill looks weird. The following is the code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{systeme}      
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
   

\begin{document}

\section{Problem 2:}
Because all the constraints as well as the function to maximize are linear, by the graphical method, we only need to check corners of the feasible region, which looks like: 

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x_1$,
    ylabel = $x_2$,
    ymin=0, ymax=10
]
%Below the first constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=red, 
    domain= 0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{(x -4)/2};

%Here the second constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=blue, 
    domain=0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
{3+x};

%Here the third constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=green, 
domain= 0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=green,
    ]
{2};

\path[name path=redgreen,
    intersection segments={of=red and green,
    sequence=A1 -- B0,},
];

\addplot [gray] fill between[of = blue and redgreen]; 



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

These codes produced

[image]

Could someone explain what happened and try to fix it? I only want the area between the red, green, and blue line filled. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is your \documentclass?

Comment: @JordanWang -- please see if the answer meets your requirement

Comment: I think that you should change the sequence to `sequence=B0 -- A1`

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed document class as article since nothing is mentioned

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{systeme}      
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
   

\begin{document}

\section{Problem 2:}
Because all the constraints as well as the function to maximize are linear, by the 
 graphical method, we only need to check corners of the feasible region, which looks 
like: 

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x_1$,
    ylabel = $x_2$,
    ymin=0, ymax=10
]
%Below the first constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=red, 
    domain= 0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{(x -4)/2};

%Here the second constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=blue, 
    domain=0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
{3+x};

%Here the third constraint is defined
\addplot [name path=green, 
domain= 0:15, 
    samples=100, 
    color=green,
    ]
{2};

\path [
    name path=gr,
    intersection segments={of=green and red,
    sequence={L1 -- R2}%------the first segment of green and second segment of red
}];

\addplot [gray] fill between[of = blue and gr]; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```